# iTunesStore not showing update button for app

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-store

We have implemented Force Update Functionality inside our App.  And it’s working fine and showing Update alert in my App.

On clicking update i am opening the following url:

```
var strAppstoreLink = itms://itunes.apple.com/za/app/<My_App_Name>/<My_App_ID>?mt=8
```

using following code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:strAppstoreLink)!)
```

it opens and redirects to app redirects to iTunesStore

> **Snap of iTunesStore opened.**

[image: snap of iTunesStore opened]

But it shows the Button text as **OPEN** not **UPDATE.**

but at same time when i open **AppStore** on the same phone at same time.

> **Snap of AppStore opened**

[image: Snap of AppStore opened]

It shows the Button text as UPDATE.

Does anyone have an idea regarding same.

Comment: This is a bug with Apple. It will happen automatically after a while. It took 2 days in my case. Mailing them didn't help.

Comment: As of my point you just drop mail to apple and may they help it out and and wait for time.

Comment: Same problem here after almost 3 months Has there been any follow up to this issue? How did you handle it?

Comment: its happen to me last week.

Comment: Not idea about it but i changed the url to the app store url instead of iTunes Store url

Comment: still having this problem, the problem is all about location. In some locations app is not ready , but why the app link says that the new app is ready to update?

Comment: @YestayMuratov please check new edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Updating the url as following worked for me.**

Changed

```
itms://itunes.apple.com/za/app/<My_App_Name>/<My_App_ID>?mt=8
```

To

```
https://itunes.apple.com/za/app/<My_App_Name>/<My_App_ID>?mt=8
```

Comment: Unfortunately this change did not appear to fix the problem for me. After reading this forum [(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52767)](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52767) the official Apple response is as follows:

"The App Store is global in nature, and it may take time for an update to an app to be available in any given store front in any given region."

Comment: Yes that might be the case. 
But in my case i was opening iTunes store instead of App Store. 
So the above change worked to stop my trouble

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem. it seems like the solution is to re-direct to this link:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/{AppID}
```

and NOT this like:

```
itms://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/{AppID}
```

this will re-direct to Appstore app and not to iTunes store app!

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be that your device has an older version of iOS installed than the new version of the app requires.

To determine if so, uninstall the app, then try to download the new one from the app store.

This was the case for me.